# Javascript onClick event not firing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Javascript to control a web form. Here is all my Javascript code and what I am trying to achieve added to it as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadPage(url){
        $(".body").fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(".body").load(url);
            $(".body").fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
    loadPage("pages/login.html");

    $("#button").on("click", function(){
        var pageTo = this.name;
        loadPage("pages/" + pageTo + ".html");
    });
});
```

The code will do more complex things later on, but it doesn't even run the above.

My form looks like this

```
<FORM>
    <SPAN class='header'>Login</SPAN><BR/>
    <LABEL for='username' class='loginLabel'>Username</LABEL>
    <INPUT type='text' id='username' name='username' value='' />
    <LABEL for='password'class='loginLabel'>Password</LABEL>
    <INPUT type='password' id='password' name='password' value='' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='process' value='login' />
    <INPUT type='button' value='Login' name='index' id='button' />
</FORM>
```

Its a simple login form, but the text does not show up in the console when the button is clicked. I don't want to use a submit button and the JQuery .submit() event because I want the same code to work with multiple types of things, including links and possibly other elements.

Comment: This is not how you bind event handlers with jQuery. I suggest to have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/.

Comment: I did. It didn't work either. If you read the other answers I added comments to it and none of them seemed to work either.

Comment: Then there is something you are not telling us (maybe problems with other code on your page) , because it works: http://jsfiddle.net/RbzAR/.

Comment: Are you including the JQuery library? There are a lot of things that can play into this.

Comment: Yes I am, or there would be errors in the chrome console

Comment: I assume `pages/login.html` contains the form? At the moment you bind the event handler, the element does not exist yet, so it cannot be bound. Bind the event handler *after* you included the content or use event delegation.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, it does. Then how would I go about fixing that? Event delegation? Mind explaining? Or linking to an explanation?

Comment: @legobear154: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/, section *Direct and delegated events*. Also useful in this context: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.

Comment: Added a proper answer ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to bind the event handler before the element exists in the page.

Either bind the handler **after** you added the form by passing a callback to `.load`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadPage(url){
        $(".body").fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(".body").load(url, function() {
                $("#button").on("click", function(){
                    var pageTo = this.name;
                    loadPage("pages/" + pageTo + ".html");
                });
            });
            $(".body").fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
    loadPage("pages/login.html");
});
```

or use event delegation (see section *Direct and delegated events* in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on)):

```
$(document).on("click", "#button", function(){
    var pageTo = this.name;
    loadPage("pages/" + pageTo + ".html");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery objects have no `onClick` method. Use [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Your code should look like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/ad3c2/)

Answer (score 3):

that's not the right way, to register a handler with jquery...

try

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("#button")` returns a jQuery object for which there is no `onclick` property/method. Use `.click`:

```
$('#button').click(function() {

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. I get nothing in the console and I even tried alert and it did nothing either

Comment: Wrap your JS code in a document.ready function: `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: Did that from the beginning, didn't feel it was important to include in the above code

Comment: Yes it does, the last input it of type button with id of button

Comment: It must  be something else you're doing because the code you have provided us works fine -- http://jsfiddle.net/vQZCL/

Comment: @FelixKling It doesn't work in Firefox for me either... I will update first post with all the code I have

Answer (score 2):

try with `.on`

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Same result as before. Nothing shows in the console. And I get no errors either.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're waiting for the document to be loaded before assigning the onclick behavior to your button? Try changing the assignment to be inside

```
$(document).ready(function(...))
```

Comment: I do wait for the document to be loaded. I didn't feel like it was important to add that to the above code though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `onclick` it's `click`

```
$("#button").click();
```